# When typing in localhost in browser, some file other than index.html pop up

Tags: apache2, php

The default file in /var/www/ is index.html. According to a tutorial i saw on youtube its contents were to show when typing in "localhost" in the browser. I am using apache2.

Sorry for the lack of explaining, I'm new.

Answer (score 0):

In the new Apache release, the `index.html` files have to be moved to `/var/www/html/`.

Move all files from `/var/www/` to `/var/www/html/` by typing in console:

`sudo mv /var/www/* /var/www/html/`

Then, restart apache with:

`service apache2 restart`.